# how to make a function that would calculate the sum of the five terms of an arithmetic progression?

Tags: javascript, html

how to make a function that would calculate the sum
of the five terms of an arithmetic progression, but the parameters of the function – the initial term and
the difference – are entered by the user.
I tried this but i have no idea what to do

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>
function progress(){
var i, x = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{x += i}
}
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function will work.

```js
function calculate(initialTerm , diff) // 1 , 1
{
  let sum = 0;
  let term = initialTerm;  //1
  for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    sum+=term;   //1 3 6 10 15
    term+=diff;  // 2 3 4 5  
  }
  console.log(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The sum of first n terms in an AP is given by - `n/2*[2a+(n-1)d]` where n is the number of terms, a is initial value and d is the difference.

So you can use the following function -

```
function progress(a, d) {
     return 5/2*[2*a + 4 * d];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sumOfAP(a, d, n) {
        var valn = document.getElementById("val-n").value;
        var vala = document.getElementById("val-a").value;
        var vald = document.getElementById("val-d").value;
        
          let sum = (valn / 2) * (2 * vala + (valn - 1) * vald);
          //return sum;
            alert(sum);
      }
```

```html
<input type="text" value="20" placeholder="Type something..." id="val-n">
  <input type="text" value="2.5" placeholder="Type something..." id="val-a">
  <input type="text" value="1.5" placeholder="Type something..." id="val-d">
    <button type="button" onclick="sumOfAP();">Get Value</button>
```